# how to add millions object to arraylist in java without having out of memory error

Tags: java

I want to add 5000000 elements to an `ArrayList` and write that `ArrayList` to a file, but I encounter an `OutOfMemoryException`. I use a for-loop to add the objects to the `ArrayList`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add more than 50,000,000 records in arraylist from mysql database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159988/how-to-add-more-than-50-000-000-records-in-arraylist-from-mysql-database)

Comment: Where are the records coming from?

Comment: could you describe your record.. also are you doing this in a production application?

Comment: Can't you write the records to the file in chunks instead of all loading them into a list to write the datas from the list just after?

Comment: I mean records are objects that i create and add to arraylist.

Comment: How much memory does a single object take ? Refer to this answer for cost model : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320980/steps-in-the-memory-allocation-process-for-java-objects

Comment: If you are instantiating objects by yourself, do you really need to add them all to a list before you write them to a file ? Can't you just write them to file as you instantiate them?

Comment: I only know that when i test it with 1M objects it's okay and the size of the file is about 56MB.

Comment: cuz i use objectoutputstream.

Comment: If you're adding 5M records to an ArrayList your design is flawed.  What are you trying to do since this might be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

If you're in control of creating the `ArrayList`, use the constructor which takes the initial capacity as argument. This way you prevent unnecessary copy operations too.

```
// This alone takes about 20 MB of RAM with 4 byte addresses
List<Object> l = new ArrayList<>(5000000);
```

If this doesn't help, don't buffer all you objects, write them directly to a file.

Comment: i try to do that too, but it not help at all.

Comment: Well, did you try to write the objects to a file directly?